# How to capture image of Linux VM without losing data

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to take an image of currently running Linux VM to set a reserved IP. But the problem is that I dont want to lose any data of current VM. When i checked in the site, it says that you want to reset the data to create a generalized image of that VM. So if I want to take a specialized VM, how to do that? could you please give the syntax? Is am doing right way to take specialized image of VM?

Answer (score 1):

You could look to capture a snapshot of the underlying Linux .vhd page blob in Azure storage, and work with that. There are several blog posts and guidance posts all over the internet here akin to using blob snapshots to backup Azure virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But its not classic VM. So there is no way to capture from web portal.

Comment: @Ramesh did you find the solution?